# Do Python Exceptions go up the Call stack?

Tags: python, error-handling, callstack

In Python, if Function A calls Function B, and Function B calls Function C, and Function C throws a ValueError (as an example), does the error make its way up the call stack so that Function A also throws a ValueError? So for example can I catch the value error from Function C in Function A?

Also, what if you create your own Exception that is defined in Function C only, will it also go up the Call stack so that Function A throws the same error?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: What you asked here is a simple thing that you can check yourself.

Comment: I'm wondering how the concept of exceptions could work without them being passed up the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does the error make its way up the call stack so that Function A also throws a ValueError?

Let's try it and see.

```
def a():
    try:
        b()
    except ValueError:
        print("Caught a value error in `a`.")

def b():
    c()

def c():
    raise ValueError

a()
```

Result:

```
Caught a value error in `a`.
```

Yep, looks like the error makes its way up the call stack.

> what if you create your own Exception that is defined in Function C only, will it also go up the Call stack so that Function A throws the same error?

Let's try it and see.

```
def a():
    try:
        b()
    except:
        print("Caught some kind of exception in `a`.")

def b():
    c()

def c():
    class MyCustomException(Exception):
        pass
    raise MyCustomException

a()
```

Result:

```
Caught some kind of exception in `a`.
```

Yep, custom exceptions make their way up the call stack too. But you aren't going to be able to do `except MyCustomException:` in `a`, since that name only exists in `c`. For this reason, where practical, declare classes at the global scope.